# Python: Split string such that each substring is a key in a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dataframe, dictionary

I have a sample string:

`"green apple, sly fox, cunning quick fox fur, cool water, yellow sand"`

and a dictionary:

```
strr_dict = {"green": "color", "apple": "fruit", "sly": "behavior", "fox": "animal", "cunning": "behavior", "quick fox": "animal", "cool water": "drink", "yellow": "color", "sand": "matter"}
```

I want to display substrings in the string with their values from the dictionary as a dataframe. This is what I have done:

```
    import pandas as pd

    sample_str = "green apple, sly fox, cunning quick fox fur, cool water, yellow sand"
    strr_dict = {"green": "color", "apple": "fruit", "sly": "behavior", "fox": "animal", "cunning": "behavior", "quick fox": "animal", "cool water": "drink", "yellow": "color", "sand": "matter"}

    df_list = []
    stripped_list = [i.strip() for i in sample_str.split(',')]
    
    for i in stripped_list:
      if i in strr_dict:
        df_list.append([i, strr_dict[i]])
      else:
        for j in i.split(): 
          if j in strr_dict:
              df_list.append([j, strr_dict[j]])
          else:
            df_list.append([j, ""])
    
    strr_df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['Text', 'Value'])
    print(strr_df)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
             Text      Value
    0        green     color
    1        apple     fruit
    2          sly     behavior
    3          fox     animal
    4      cunning     behavior
    5        quick          
    6          fox     animal
    7          fur          
    8   cool water     drink
    9       yellow     color
    10        sand     matter
```

My desired output is:

```
             Text      Value
    0        green     color
    1        apple     fruit
    2          sly     behavior
    3          fox     animal
    4      cunning     behavior
    5    quick fox     animal
    6          fur          
    7   cool water     drink
    8       yellow     color
    9         sand     matter
```

I want to display the values if the substrings are an exact match with the dictionary keys. I am wondering how to split the string accordingly. In this case, `cunning quick fox fur` should be split as `cunning`, `quick fox`, `fur`. But this may not be the case always, sometimes it should be split as `cunning`, `quick fox fur` to get their values from the dictionary. I am very confused on how to handle this case.

Comment: `"green apple, sly fox, cunning quick fox fur, cool water, yellow sand"`
so sometimes each word, seperated by space, is a key, but sometimes two words belong together as one key? the input is very confusing

Comment: @ Flying Thunder, Yes exactly. Sometimes each word is a key, sometimes 2 or more words together is a key.

Comment: @Animeartist What is the logic? How should the computer know when two words belong together, and when they don't?

Comment: youd have to check every `,` seperated string against all dictionary keys checking if a key is contained here, and then, when multiple keys (a one word, and a two word - e.g. quick fox and fox) - then what? your example seems to only want the longest match, so that sounds doable, but (i know this is a stackoverflow clichee), it sounds like it would be way easier to just make sure your input is properly formated

Comment: @FlyingThunder, Yes it's possible to check every key like that but I was looking for a more efficient solution though.

Comment: i cant see how you can get more efficient than that - without iterating over the dictionary keys the programm has no way of knowing what words it should save away out of e.g. `cunning quick fox fur`, from your code example at least not

Answer (score 0):

So this does give the output you specified. I dont know how and why you would want this, and i dont know if this works for the other input cases you might have, but it should - feel free to test with whatever other eldritch data sets you have ready.

```
import pandas as pd

sample_str = "green apple, sly fox, cunning quick fox fur, cool water, yellow sand"
strr_dict = {"green": "color", "apple": "fruit", "sly": "behavior", "fox": "animal", "cunning": "behavior",
             "quick fox": "animal", "cool water": "drink", "yellow": "color", "sand": "matter"}

df_list = []
stripped_list = [i.strip() for i in sample_str.split(',')]


checklist = []

for i in stripped_list:
    if i in strr_dict:
        df_list.append([i, strr_dict[i]])
        checklist.append(i)
    else:
        for z in list(strr_dict.keys()):
            if z in str(checklist):
                continue
            if z in i:
                try:
                    df_list.append([i, strr_dict[i]])
                    checklist.append(i)
                except:
                    df_list.append([z, strr_dict[z]])
                    checklist.append(z)
    for x in i.split():
        if x not in str(checklist) and x not in list(strr_dict.keys()):
            df_list.append([x, ""])



strr_df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=['Text', 'Value'])
print(strr_df)
```

Output:

```
         Text     Value
0       green     color
1       apple     fruit
2         sly  behavior
3         fox    animal
4     cunning  behavior
5   quick fox    animal
6         fur          
7  cool water     drink
8      yellow     color
9        sand    matter

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, It's working for most of the cases. For cases like: `cunning quick fox fur yellow sand`, it's working for this string, but the `yellow sand` at the end, after `cool water` doesn't get displayed. This is part of an NLP process that I was trying to do, and I wanted to display the values as a dataframe though.

Comment: what do you mean - what is your input in the case where its not working? when i use this input `"green apple, sly fox, cunning quick fox fur yellow sand, cool water"` its still working